# Postgres Custom float type that is always truncated to 2 decimals after point

Tags: postgresql

Can I generate a custom data type in postgres that everytime I insert or update a float into it it is truncate to 2 decimals after dot.

```
create table money(

   formatted moneys_type
);

insert into money values (30.122323213);

Select * from money;
```

Returns

```
30.12
```

Update I didn't use numeric or decimal because they round up when 1.999 => 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [documentation on Numeric Types / Arbitrary Precision Numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html).

> The *precision* of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in
> the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the
> decimal point. The *scale* of a numeric is the count of decimal digits
> in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. So the
> number 23.5141 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4. Integers can be
> considered to have a scale of zero.
>
> ...
>
> To declare a column of type numeric use the syntax:

```
NUMERIC(precision, scale)
```

> The maximum allowed precision when explicitly specified in the type declaration is 1000.

So you can use

```
NUMERIC(1000, 2)
```

Comment: Hi Adan thanks, but the only problem is that numeric and decimal types round the number when storing something like 10.999 it is rounded to 11, is there anyway to stop it from rounding it.

Comment: Well, that makes it a whole different question. You would need to use `trunc` function somewhere in between. You may try to [CREATE CAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html).